# New top bar bug with reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, notification-bar

The reputation is showing is correct, but the dropdown is showing it bad. This is what it shows to me:

[image]

I actually gained 20 reputation, which is correct, but the ones in gaming.stackexchange.com are limited somehow, or not showing tag wiki edits, leading to confusion:

[image]

Comment: You need to refresh the page to see the current data.

Comment: @juergend is correct, they're still working on the live update so if this still happens after the top bar is released over the network it would be actual bug.

Comment: I've also seen this bug once before, I think it showed `+80` while I only have `13` new rep

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Refreshing did not actually solve the problem

Comment: @SysDragon so this means you lost 8 reputation somehow; this won't be reflected in the live update the won't be reduced.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I readed your answer before posting this. Does not look the same problem. This is not related to achievements and my green number of reputation is correct

Comment: Ah, indeed, sorry, I skimmed over your post on my iPhone and didn't read it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag wikis and such are now shown in the achievements dropdown, they were missing from the initial version and added later on.